# Raspberry PIs for NOC displays

Tags: pi-2, display, chromium

We want to serve NOC information on 3 displays in our office, and are considering using Raspberry PIs for that (3x http://www.amazon.de/Raspberry-Modell-Quad-Starter-Bundle/dp/B00T7OHE9A/). Our NOC information is simply a web page that we need to view in a browser.

Two questions:

- Does this model support running Google Chromium at a 1920x1080 resolution?
- We just need the Raspberry PIs as "end-users", we would like to avoid tinkering with the hardware and software running on it. Considering this, does this configuration (using Raspberry PI simply to display a auto-refresh webpage) make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should support the full 1920-1080

As for getting it

`sudo apt-get install chromium`

Then

`sudo apt-get update`

Using for a refreshing webpage will be no issue.

Comment: Do the `update` *before* the install -- see `man apt-get` for an understanding of why.   You may also want to do an `apt-get upgrade` immediately after `update` while you are at it; this applies to new systems as well as old ones since the SD card images are only created periodically.

Comment: Chromium didn't work on my raspberry pi 2 (no apt-get match), but iceweasel is doing the job just as fine. Thanks!

Comment: @vvanscherpenseel I'm sorry that didn't work and glad you found a way!